# Ionic 5 toastController doesn't show "close" button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I migrated from Ionic 4 to Ionic 5 and noticed my toastControllers are not showing the "close" button even if I set up the ToastOptions properties with **showCloseButton: true**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it adding explicitly the buttons array like this:

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'User was added successfully',
    showCloseButton: true,
    position: 'top',
    buttons: [
          {
            text: "close",
            handler: () => {
              console.log('Close clicked');
            }
          }
        ]
  });
```